# lua lxp The specified module could not be found

Tags: lua

I'm putting together an application that uses the moon soap, but when you run it reports the following error :

> C:\Lua\5.1\lua.exe: error loading module 'lxp' from file 'C:\Lua\5.1\clibs\lxp.dll':
>   The specified module could not be found.

How do I fix this ?

Comment: Check if `clibs/lxp.dll` exists?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a "file not found" error.  Note that the message stated that it tried to load the module "lxp" from a file ('C:\Lua\5.1\clibs\lxp.dll') but it didn't work.  Maybe the file doesn't have a luaopen_lxp C function (which might be called by loadlib)...  Or maybe you are not loading it with require...